# Right type when returning anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have letter and user tables in database:

1. `User("Id", "Name")`
2. `Letter("Id", "UserId", "Title")`

and i use this code in class for get letter list:

```
public static mytype GetList()
{
     var lst = (from l in Letters.ToList()
               select new {l.Id, l.Title, l.tblUsers.Name}).ToList();
     return lst;
}
```

please help me for choosing the right type. i want not use this code:

```
public static List<Letter> GetList()
{
     List<Letter> lst = new List<Letter>();
     lst = (from l in Letters.ToList()
            select l).ToList();
     return lst;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to return List<Letter> and want to return some custom data type or list of some other type of object?

Comment: I create objLetter class in C# with (Id, Title, Name) property, but i can not get my list with linq and  List<objLetter> would fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a type for this.

```
new {l.Id, l.Title, l.tblUsers.Name}
```

is the definition of an anonymous class. To use it as a return value, you should define a `struct` or `class` which represents the information you want to return. You can use `dynamic`, but it will easily lead to runtime errors when you change the returned data structure as the callers of the method will not know how the return value looks like.

For example:

```
struct UserLetter { 
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string AuthorName {get;set;}
}

public static IList<UserLetter> GetList()
{
     return (from l in Letters
            select new UserLetter
            { Id = l.Id, Title = l.Title, AuthorName = l.tblUsers.Name}).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an anonymous type so either you can create a new class holding the properties you're interested in or use dynamic objects

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetList()
{
     var lst = (from l in Letters.ToList()
               select new {Id = l.Id, Title = l.Title, UserName = l.tblUsers.Name}).ToList();
     return lst;
}
```

Then in your calling code just iterate over the dynamics objects and call the dynamic properties

```
foreach (var dynamicObject in GetList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.UserName);
}
```

Unless your dynamic objects have a very small scope in your application, a new class would probably be a better choice since you'll benefit from type-checks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
class mytype
{ 
 public int id;
 public string title;
 public string name;
}
public static List<mytype> GetList()
{
 return (from l in Letters.ToList() select new mytype{id=l.Id,title=l.Title,  name=l.tblUsers.Name}).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a join with user table.

```
public static List<objLetter> GetList()
{
 List<objLetter> lst = new List<objLetter>();
 lst = from ltr in Letters
       join user in Users on ltr.UserId equals user.UserId
       select new objLetter {Id = ltr.Id , Title = ltr.Title, Name = user.Name })
 return lst;
}
```